# syntax error at or near "AS" in creating trigger in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

Good day,

I'm having trouble with my query, as I can't seem to understand why I keep getting the error "syntax error at or near "AS" here's my query:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER  updateAvailableQuantity
    AFTER INSERT ON sale_item FOR EACH ROW 
    AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.quantity > 0 THEN
        UPDATE products
        SET products.quantity_instock = products.quantity_instock - NEW.quantity WHERE barcode =  NEW.barcode;
        END IF;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

the error that I keep getting is,

```
    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
    LINE 4: AS $$
            ^
    SQL state: 42601
    Character: 100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not write trigger in PostgreSQL in this way. Here its a 2 step process.

1. First create a Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateAvailableQuantity()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.quantity > 0 THEN
    UPDATE products
    SET quantity_instock = quantity_instock - NEW.quantity WHERE products.barcode =  NEW.barcode;
    END IF;

RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

2. Then write the trigger on your table to call the function like below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER  trg_updateAvailableQuantity
AFTER INSERT ON sale_item 
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE updateAvailableQuantity();
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally, it worked. I was in complete enigma as why this wasn't working and in mysql workbench, it works completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your syntax. See the [documentation page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) on `create trigger`.

`FOR EACH ROW` can not go before `REFERENCING AS` statement.

The documentation also has a plenty examples.