# How to trigger an update for an attribute in a row in a table based on change in attributes in other tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table A, table B and a join table A_B.

Table A

```
| id | a_active |
| -- | -------- |
| a1 | true     |
```

Table B

```
| id | b_active |
| -- | -------- |
| b1 | false    |
```

Table A_B - Primary Key unique(`a_id`, `b_id`) and foreign keys referncing A and B respectively.

```
| id | a_id_fk | b_id_fk | active |
| -- | ------- | ------- | ------ |
| j1 | a1      | b1      | false  |
```

So, whenever there is a change in value of `a_active` or `b_active`, I want `active` to change based on the condition `a_active && b_active`.

Also, I should be able to change `active` to `false` but to change to `true`, it should perform the above check.

I was looking into triggers and feel it might help me with this usecase but I am not sure how to go about it. Please help.

Comment: You would maintain this with a trigger.  But why bother?  Why not just use `join`, so the value is always up-to-date.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'd want to query A_B based on `active` alone. Wouldn't it be better to avoid `join` then? The values won't change often.

Comment: instead of Separate table update create a view `A_B`.

Comment: 'Also, I should be able to change active to false but to change to true, it should perform the above check.'  So if you manually set a_b.active to false, but then a_active gets changed to false, and then back to true again, should a_b.active also get changed to true automatically?  Or does it have to remember it was manually overridden?

Comment: @jjanes I understand your question now, so I deleted my previous comment which I misunderstood and would potentially would confuse you.
> does it have to remember it was manually overridden?
Yes, I'd prefer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want active data (which I assume is the intention) use:

```
select ab.*
from a_b ab join
     a
     on ab.a_id_fk = a.id join
     b
     on ab.b_id_fk = b.id
where a.active and b.active;
```

There is little to be gained from storing a redundant column an `a_b` with this information.  It adds overhead when data changes in either `a` or `b` -- potentially a lot of changes, actually.  It makes each column a bit wider, so the table takes up more space.  And joins to `a` and `b` should be quite fast.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, you have three active flags, so the `where` would be:

```
where a.active and b.active and ab.active
```

Comment: You are right but for my usecase, `active` in `a_b` can be `false` (directly updating `active` in `a_b`) regardless of `a_active` and `b_active` both being `true`. Please check my second last point.

Comment: @ManpreetKrishan . . . That just means that you need an additional flag, not that it should be maintained using a trigger.

Comment: I have accepted your answer as it covers my usecase in every way. Simple and elegant. I wasn't well-versed with triggers and thought they will help my usecase and that joins are bad. So this only clouded my thinking and hence I couldn't understand your answer at first, and after the edit (where in you missed my other usecase), it perfectly answers my question. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

Recommended way is to write a view like below:

```
create view viewA_B as 
select 
t1.id,t1.a_id_fk,t1.b_id_fk, ((t2.a_active) and (t3.b_active)) "active"
from a_b t1 
inner join tabA t2 on t2.id=t1.a_id_fk
inner join tabB t3 on t3.id=t1.b_id_fk
```

Then you can use the view like below:

```
select   * from viewA_B where active=false;
```

But still you want to write the trigger. Then you have to write 2 triggers. one is on tableA and second on tableB. Use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64346315/syntax-error-at-or-near-as-in-creating-trigger-in-postgresql/64346695#64346695)

Trigger Function of Table A

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateA()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$
BEGIN
update a_b t1
    SET "active" = (new.a_active and t2.b_active)
    from tabB t2 where t2.id=t1.b_id_fk and t1.a_id_fk=NEW.id;
    
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Trigger on table A

```
CREATE TRIGGER  trg_update_a
AFTER UPDATE ON tabA 
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE updateA();
```

Trigger Function of Table B

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateB()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$
BEGIN
update a_b t1
    SET "active" = (new.b_active and t2.a_active)
    from tabA t2 where t2.id=t1.a_id_fk and t1.b_id_fk=NEW.id;
    
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Trigger on table B

```
CREATE TRIGGER  trg_update_b
AFTER UPDATE ON tabB 
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE updateB();
```

**EDIT**: as per comment

You want to validate the update in `a_b` then you can use `check` constraint.

first create a function like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_active(id_a varchar, id_b varchar,val bool) 
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
  declare check_b bool;
  declare check_a bool;
  begin
  select a_active into check_a from tabA where id=id_a;
  select b_active into check_b from tabB where id=id_b;

if val then
return (check_b and check_a);
else
return true;
end if;
  
  end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

then alter your table and add a check constraint like below:

```
alter table a_b add CONSTRAINT valid_val CHECK(validate_active(a_id_fk,b_id_fk,active))
```

above will check the changes on field `active` in table `a_b` as per your condition.
[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3e05431851ca456db9b4c5a58918cc81)

Comment: This helps with triggers. But this doesn't address the part where I shouldn't be able to change a_b.active to true if either of the values in a or b are false.

Edit: > Also, I should be able to change active to false but to change to true, it should perform the above check.

Comment: Edited the answer and added the required changes.

Comment: This has solved my usecase. Thanks! However, let's say I manually over-ride `a_b.active` to `false` and `a_active` was changed to `false`, then `true` and if `b.active` is `true`, this will trigger and update `a_b.active` to `true`. I want to avoid that in the case of manual over-riding to `false`. I think a flag column has to be set for this specifically then? Thanks again.

Comment: I have accepted the other answer now as it solves my usecase fully and is simple. However, I learnt a great deal about triggers, views, functions from this answer. Thank you for answering with your effort and time! Sorry & thank you!